# Python scraping problem "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "ResultSet") to str"

Tags: python

I am fresh noobster who tries to learn python as well as use it for webscraping.
So I watched a few videos to learn the basics on youtube, followed the tutorial, however I cannot figure it out why my code does not work.

Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/global/lt-en/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphic%20card'

#opening up the connection grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#HTML parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs all containers
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

filename= "123.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "brand, product_name, product_price\n"

f.write(headers)


for container in containers:
    brand = container.findAll("a",{"class":"title"})

    title_container = container.findAll("a",{"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    price_container = container.findAll("li",{"class":"price-current"})
    product_price = price_container[0].text.strip()

print("brand: " + brand)
print("product_name: " + product_name)
print("product_price: " + product_price)

f.write(brand + "," + product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + product_price + "\n")

f.close()
```

**Here is the error I get:**

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>firstwebscrape.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\31947\Documents\Python\firstwebscrape.py", line 34, in <module>
    print("brand: " + brand)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "ResultSet") to str
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: The error message suggests you get a set of results, that is, a set of (likely) strings. You can iterate over the set, getting each individual string, and print/append/whatever that string in the loop.

Comment: The error says it all. brand variable is not a string. If you see your other prints it's actually taking text of the first element. You can follow the similar logic and get the text of the first element.

Comment: Try `print("brand: ", brand)` (comma, no plus) for starters.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try `print('brand: ' + str(brand))` to coerce `brand` into a string for concatenation.

Comment: Also note you assign `brand` again and again *inside* the for loop, overwriting each previous value, and the value you print *outside* the for loop will only be the last value.

Comment: Thank you guys for answers. @00 @Green Cloak Guy @PraveenB
So I changed to : `print("brand: ", brand)`

Now I get:
`f.write(brand + "," + product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + product_price + "\n")
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list`

Comment: Please ask one question per question, and certainly not through comments. Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not well suited for mailing list style question-answer back-and-forth, nor is it meant to be. Perhaps something like the python-tutor mailing list can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is due to the type of `brand`, and I think you have an answer in the comments.

But, you have an issue when you get the brand name. Check in the following the solution. I get the brand name from the `img` tag:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/global/lt-en/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphic%20card'

# opening up the connection grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

# HTML parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

# grabs all containers
containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item-container"})

filename = "123.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "brand, product_name, product_price\n"

f.write(headers)

for container in containers:
    brand = container.findAll("img", {"class": " lazy-img"})[1]['title']

    title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class": "item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    price_container = container.findAll("li", {"class": "price-current"})
    product_price = price_container[0].text.strip()

    print("brand: " + brand)
    print("product_name: " + product_name)
    print("product_price: " + product_price)

    f.write(brand + "," + product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + product_price + "\n")

f.close()
```

Output:

```
brand: ASUS
product_name: ASUS ROG Strix GeForce RTX 2080 Ti DirectX 12 ROG-STRIX-RTX2080TI-11G-GAMING Video Card
product_price: €1.171,99 

–
brand: Sapphire Tech
product_name: Sapphire PULSE Radeon RX 570 4GB GDDR5 PCI-E Dual HDMI / DVI-D / Dual DP OC w/ Backplate (UEFI), 100412P4GOCL
product_price: €120,99 

–
brand: GIGABYTE
product_name: GIGABYTE GeForce RTX 2070 Super WINDFORCE OC 3X 8G Graphics Card, GV-N207SWF3OC-8GD
product_price: €468,99 (3 Offers)

–
brand: ASUS
product_name: ASUS ROG Strix GeForce RTX 2080 Ti DirectX 12 ROG-STRIX-RTX2080TI-O11G-GAMING Video Card
product_price: €1.159,99 (2 Offers)

–
brand: MSI
product_name: MSI GeForce GTX 1660 DirectX 12 GTX 1660 VENTUS XS 6G OC Video Card
product_price: €200,99 (3 Offers)

–
brand: GIGABYTE
product_name: GIGABYTE Radeon RX 570 DirectX 12 GV-RX570GAMING-4GD REV2.0 Video Card
product_price: €113,99 (2 Offers)

–
brand: EVGA
product_name: EVGA GeForce RTX 2060 SC Ultra GAMING, 06G-P4-2067-KR, 6GB GDDR6, Dual HDB Fans
product_price: €334,99 (3 Offers)

–
brand: ASUS
product_name: ASUS Dual GeForce RTX 2080 Ti DirectX 12 DUAL-RTX2080TI-O11G Video Card
product_price: €1.096,99 (2 Offers)

–
brand: EVGA
product_name: EVGA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER XC GAMING, 08G-P4-3172-KR
product_price: €510,99 (3 Offers)

–
brand: ASUS
product_name: ASUS ROG Strix Radeon RX 570 O4G Gaming OC Edition GDDR5 DP HDMI DVI VR Ready AMD Graphics Card (ROG-STRIX-RX570-O4G-GAMING)
product_price: €132,99 

–
brand: ZOTAC
product_name: ZOTAC GeForce GTX 1060 DirectX 12 ZT-P10620A-10M Video Card
product_price: €199,99 

–
brand: ASUS
product_name: ASUS ROG STRIX GeForce RTX 2060 SUPER DirectX 12 ROG-STRIX-RTX2060S-A8G-GAMING Video Card
product_price: €403,99 (2 Offers)
```

Comment: Please verify Your code it will give an index out of range error 
      
       brand = container.findAll("img", {"class": " lazy-img"})[1]['title']
       IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: ijust copy and paste it . and using python3.6 still getting index error


/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/carmel-infintor/Documents/odoo_new_13/custom/addons/xml_read.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/carmel-infintor/Documents/odoo_new_13/custom/addons/xml_read.py", line 44, in <module>
    brand = container.findAll("img", {"class": " lazy-img"})[1]['title']
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1

Answer (score 1):

Hi In the above code You are trying to concatenate a "string" with a "list" using "+" symbol

```
print("brand: " + brand)
```

Change the above line to

```
print("brand: " + str(brand)) 
#or
print("brand: " , brand)
```

Also Change

```
   f.write(str(brand) + "," + product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + product_price + "\n") # convert brand to string here
```

So The complete code will be like this

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/global/lt-en/Video-Cards-Video- 
Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphic%20card'

#opening up the connection grabbing the page
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#HTML parser
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

#grabs all containers
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

filename= "123.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "brand, product_name, product_price\n"

f.write(headers)


for container in containers:
    brand = container.findAll("a",{"class":"title"})

    title_container = container.findAll("a",{"class":"item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    price_container = container.findAll("li",{"class":"price-current"})
    product_price = price_container[0].text.strip()

print("brand: " + str(brand))
print("product_name: " + product_name)
print("product_price: " + product_price)

f.write(str(brand) + "," + product_name.replace(",", "|") + "," + product_price + "\n")

f.close()
```